# Cause of photoluminescence in CaV2O6

Tags: photochemistry

I had prepared the sample of Cav2O6 using solid-state reaction route. I had done XRD, SEM-EDS which all matched with the previous results. There was something strange when I did the PL analysis. I saw that most of the vanadates gave the yellow-orange spectra but my sample was giving dark blue. I was not able to find anything related to that in previous researches.

So, I thought that CaV2O6 must also have the properties of CaO as (CaV2O6=CaO-V2O5). I searched the PL studies of CaO and the results were matching closely. So, can I conclude that at a particular excitation wavelength, the properties of CaO component of my sample are more prominent.

Comment: Did you took an excitation spectrum? Literature?

Comment: Yes, I took the excitation spectrum. For CaV2O6, only one previous research has taken Photoluminescence and excitation spectrum but with CaV2O6 in the form of nanorods. Other papers include the excitation and emission of CaV2O7.

Comment: So you likely have a two (or more) phase sample, so are happily seeing PL from the CaO bits.

Comment: But the XRD results does not indicate any additional sample. The variations between the undoped and doped XRD are extremely minor (marginal peak shifts and increase in intensity).